# scroll key down background div

Tags: html, scroll

Hi I'm trying to scroll a div (that is behind two main divs) by typing down arrow key but it doesn't work. This is the site http://trendetic.com If I click on the ul list of photos, down key works fine, but I want to use down key to scroll th list of photos without make a mouse click on it.

These are the nested divs:

```
<div class="main row scroll-y" id="ppal">

<div id="centrado" class="centrado">
<ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">
```

I want to scroll the grid with the down key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus the div you want to scroll.

```
<div id="ppal" tabindex="1">...</div>
```

Make sure to add the tabindex attribute to the div.

jQuery:

```
$('#ppal').focus();
```